# Mongodb/Express/Handlebars have res.render wait until after data is pulled

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

It seems that res.render is loading before data has been pulled from the mongodb. Is there anyway around this.

```
app.use('/portfolio/:item_id', function(req, res, next) {
portfolioItem.findOne({ projectID : req.params.item_id}, function (err, item){
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    if (item) {
        res.locals = {
            script: ['isotope.js'],
            title: item.projectTitle,
             projectID: item.projectID,
             projectTitle: item.projectTitle,
             projectDescription: item.projectDescription,
             projectURL: item.projectURL,
             customerName: item.customerName,
             websiteCategories: item.projectCategories,
             grid: item.grid
        }
    }}); 
    res.render('case_study');
```

});

As a side note i am using handlebars as well.

Comment: res.render needs to be inside the findOne callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As snozza mentions in his comment, the `res.render` must be within the findOne callback.

This is due to Node.js and the fact that it is operating asynchronously. It runs both functions simultaneously, and doesn't wait for the data from MongoDB call to return. Within the findOne function itself, the code is run synchronously, therefore putting `res.render` after your second if statement will solve the issue.

```
app.use('/portfolio/:item_id', function(req, res, next) {
  portfolioItem.findOne({ projectID : req.params.item_id}, function (err, item){
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    if (item) {
      res.locals = {
        script: ['isotope.js'],
        title: item.projectTitle,
        projectID: item.projectID,
        projectTitle: item.projectTitle,
        projectDescription: item.projectDescription
        projectURL: item.projectURL 
        customerName: item.customerName,
        websiteCategories: item.projectCategories,
        grid: item.grid
      }
      res.render('case_study'); 
    }
  }); 
});
```